# "svn log" almost always returns "server unexpectedly closed connection"

Tags: windows-7, logging, svn

I am on a Windows 7 system and using TortoiseSVN. I have used this combination for a very long time. However, suddenly the system seems to be broken viz.:

svn update works (quite slow)

svn commit occasionally works (1 in 4 attempts work)

svn log almost never works! (Unable to connect to repository at URL:  Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection)

The only thing I changed recently was add another Samsung SSD, and check out the repo there. The problem started several days after that though. Also, going back to the old SSD doesn't quite alleviate the problem.

Hoping someone can help!

Thanks,
FrustratedUser!

Comment: Look at the server logs.

Comment: I don't have access to those. Works fine for everyone else in the office. What is so peculiar about "svn log" vs. update or commit?

Answer (score 1):

SVN update, commit, and log can be fairly server intensive, relatively. If the connection to the server has limited capacity, and/or the server itself is underpowered, it's unfortunately not uncommon for the client operation to take so long that the server disconnects the socket.

I doubt the SSD on your client has much to do with it, but tracking down the failure point can be tricky. I would start by looking at:

1. what version of svn the client has
2. what version of svn the server has
3. what the client settings are, with respect to the server, especially if there is a version mismatch. (see: https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#neon-deleted)

Sometimes this can be fixed by increasing the server timeout, but if you don't have access to the server that may not be an option.

Also take a look if there is some kind of proxy or load balancer in your network path that could have a lower connection timeout than the SVN server itself.

If the files you are working with are large and/or binary files, you may get better results by making smaller, atomic commits than by trying to do everything in one transaction.

Comment: All great points Christopher! Thank you.
- I checked on the svn version required and it said 1.9.x, so went back to 1.9.3 (no help)

- the network is a simple connection directly to the ISP router. No proxies. I am going over VPN though.

- it's usually a small # bytes of commit each time. So that may not be a issue.

I wonder though why things changed overnight just for my system.
Using TCPViewer to view my network traffic indicates the max bandwidth taken by the vpnagent (even while I have no network related tasks going - other than a couple of chrome.exe processes)